# Linux Sort multiple files - sort: multi-character tab `$\\u0001'

Tags: linux, sorting

I am trying to sort multiple files based on first four fields value.

The command i tried is

```
sort -t$'\u0001' -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3 -k4,4 * > output.dat
```

When i try this i am getting the error like

```
sort: multi-character tab `$\\u0001'
```

The delimiter used in the files is ^A (\u0001).

The output of locale is

```
LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1
LC_CTYPE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TIME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_PAPER="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_NAME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
LC_ALL=
```

Any help on this appreciated.

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: I think that should work fine. There must be something weird with your environment. Are you using `bash`? What is the output of `locale`?

Comment: I tried echo $SHELL in my terminal , the result is /bin/ksh

Comment: Ahh, well that's probably the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you're using Korn shell, try this:

```
sort -t`printf "\u0001"` -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3 -k4,4 * > output.dat
```

Comment: I tried this, i got the below error.
printf: invalid universal character name \u0001
sort: multi-character tab `-k1,1n'

Comment: actually its working on another linux server, even the command what i placed above also working in another server.. some issue with the server but i dont know how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: sort -t`printf "\1"` -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3 -k4,4 * > output.dat was working

Comment: $ time sort -t`printf "\1"` -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3 -k4,4 * > output.dat
dm-84: warning, group block quota exceeded.
dm-84: write failed, group block limit reached.
sort: write failed: /tmp/sort5RsGgE: Disk quota exceeded
  366.11s real   247.58s user    29.65s system

Comment: changed the sort command /tmp directory to some other directory where we have enough space and it was working.

Comment: @Shankar, good to hear. It sounds like you're using older unix tools, so keep in mind that not everything you read will apply to your specific system. For instance, `$'..'` doesn't work in `ksh`, and I guess it doesn't understand unicode either. Make sure you read your manuals like `man printf` or `man ksh` to get information specifically for your current system.

Answer (score 1):

Since the lowest 128 codepoints of unicode are compatible to ascii - `\u0001` is the same as `\1`.

The following command works:

```
sort -t $'\1' -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3 -k4,4 * > output.dat
```

Comment: I tried this, same error i am getting.. sort: multi-character tab `$\\1'

Comment: actually its working on another linux server, even the command what i placed above also working in another server.. some issue with the server but i dont know how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: its working for small files.. but when i try with large files ( multiple files - toatl 50 GB size), it was throwing error

$ time sort -t`printf "\1"` -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3 -k4,4 * > output.dat
dm-84: warning, group block quota exceeded.
dm-84: write failed, group block limit reached.
sort: write failed: /tmp/sort5RsGgE: Disk quota exceeded
  366.11s real   247.58s user    29.65s system

Comment: sorry, yours dont have printf. i wrongly copy pasted.. The actual issue why it was throwing quota exceeded is because of tmp directory capacity, i pointed the sort command tmp directory where i have enough space and it was working.